# Do Newton's Laws of Motion also consider internal forces?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, kinematics

Does Newton's Law of Motion also consider internal forces (like tension or compression)? or only the external forces are ONLY considered (like wind and pushing an object)?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** it depends on what *internal* means (*internal* in respect to what?)

Newton laws of motion apply to *point-like objects*. All are the forces applied to these objects are included.

Thus, if we are dealing with a container of gas, treating it as a point-like object, the internal forces are ignored. If we are considering the gas within, treating every atom/molecule as an object, the internal forces are accounted for.

Intermediate level is provided by continuum mechanics (of liquids or solids - i.e., hydrodynamics and elasticity theory): here we account for the forces that are *internal* in respect to the object, but still macroscopic in respect to the atoms/molecules composing it.

**Remark:**
Strictly speaking, when a container with a gas is treated as a whole, one still may claim to account for some of the internal forces, which cancel out due to the Newton's third law. This is notably the logic used in proving the momentum conservation. Internal forces however may include friction, i.e., convert mechanical energy to other forms of energy, which is not accounted for by the Newton's laws.

Comment: Hi, @Roger Vadim. Thank you for the thorough response. I am not sure about the internal forces. I randomly heard that F = ma considers "external or internal forces." But it did not elaborate. I found that it may include "gravity forces, magnetic force, electrical force, and spring force." However, some sources mentioned that internal forces may be "tension, compression, shear, bending, and torsion." That is why I got confused.

PS. I apologize for the dumb question. I am trying to clarify what I am trying to learn.

Comment: When considering a liquid or an elastic body, one typically takes a small volume of it and considers the forces acting on it, from teh point of view of Newton's laws. Thus, these can be called *internal* forces. On the other hand, *internal* in thermodynamic context means anything on molecular level (like *internal energy*). *Internal* is an ambiguous word, not a well-defined physical term.

Comment: Oh, I see. Internal forces could vary depending on the context. I get it now. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please note: if the internal forces don't cancel each other out, the object deforms and you probably have to start considering them as external forces. Tension/compression is *how* an object reacts to an external force, but if you need to consider them separately and they are not balanced, your object is in the process of breaking apart - earlier simplification no longer holds!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR It's not wrong to take internal forces into account, but it's unnecessary trouble.

Within an object `A`, I understand an internal force `F` as one that some part `A1` exerts on another part `A2`, both being parts of `A`.

Because of the "actio=reactio" principle, `A2` exerts a force `-F` (exactly opposite to `F`) on `A1`.

So, when looking at `A` as a whole, the two internal forces cancel out one another. Therefore it doesn't matter whether you consider the internal forces or not. If you want to take them into account, you have to do so for both the "actio" and the "reactio" part, always exactly compensating one another. Knowing that, it's of course easier to ignore internal forces right from the beginning.

E.g. internal pressure inside a (closed) bottle of soda water doesn't matter (the compressed gas interacts with the bottle's hull, both being part of the closed bottle). But as soon as you open it, the internal pressure acts against the outside world, meaning that it has an overall effect on the bottle, i.e. can accelerate the bottle.