# Why don’t we treat rigid bodies as particles only

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

We know the law $F_{net}=ma$ is for a particle. But for rigid bodies we have another law that includes COM ie $F_{ext}=Ma_{com}$. It’s done because there is rotational motion with translational which we ignore. But we also know that a rigid body can follow the same path even while rotating. So why not just use the same law that is defined for a particle ie treat it as a particle?

Comment: Who said that it is so?

Comment: Just replace $a$ with $a_{CM}$, and the formula is adequate for a rigid body.

Comment: Even after the revision, I'm still not sure what you're asking.  You *can* treat an extended rigid body as a point particle for the purposes of finding the motion of the center of mass;  the law is exactly the same, just with $a_{cm}$ instead of $a$.  Can you please clarify further what you're asking?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thank you for the reply. I am asking if a block is thrown like a bowling ball then it will have both translational and rotational motion. If we see then whole of the block travels from point A to B. ie we apply a force and it travels a distance same as COM. So why not ignore the rotational motion and treat the whole block as a particle of some size?

Comment: Who says you can't ignore the rotational motion?  If you're dealing with a problem where the rotational motion doesn't matter, or can be neglected, then yes, you can ignore the rotational motion and focus on the trajectory of the center of mass.  You probably did this implicitly when you did problems about cannonballs or billiard-ball collisions or roller coasters in your introductory mechanics class (all of which are really extended rigid bodies).  But sometimes you *can't* neglect the rotational motion, and you have to study both the rotational and translational motion simultaneously.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert can you give me an example where if we ignore rotational motion we would be doing it wrong?

Comment: @Mandark26:  A ball rolling down a ramp will end up with a lower translational speed  at the bottom than a block of the same mass sliding down a (frictionless) ramp of the same height.  The reason is that the initial gravitational potential energy of the ball is converted into translational and rotational kinetic energy, while the sliding block only has translational KE.  If you ignore the rotation of the ball, you get the wrong result.

Comment: Okay! Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Because Newton's laws are formulated for *point-like objects*.

When treating a rigid body in basic mechanics, we decompose its motion into that of its *center-of-mass* (i.e., motion of the body as a point-like object) and its rotation about the center-of-mass (for which we write the equation relating torque and angular momentum, instead of force and momentum).

See also:
[Do Newton's Laws of Motion also consider internal forces?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/689201/247642)
[When we say a rigid body is a system of particles, what exactly are 'particles' here?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712555/247642)

Comment: What if we ignore the rotational motion and just apply the usual f=ma that is for a particle? Why introduce $A_{com}$ ?
Because a body can still follow the same path while rotating as it would if it doesn’t rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Because a rigid body has more degrees of freedom than a point particle - specifically, it has an orientation and therefore also an angular velocity vector.

Answer (score 0):

Spatial or twist acceleration defines on whether there is a centre of mass or not. For a rigid body, say the Earth, we identify that you are able to deform any surface without affecting the centre of mass. However if you were to have a metal rod, without any deformation, its centre of mass is fixed, however it cannot have any polar axis or torque such that it can gravitationally create a field. You must think of everything moving in space-time, and whether that rigid body is able to move against any interactions with its field. Hence, F=ma does indeed exist for a rigid body, however you must first find a spatial partial derivative to find the maximum field and system of equations that define the acceleration in terms of the gravitational constants, CM.